# Refresh a HTML select in materialize dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, materialize

I am just filling in a materialize html select with vue.js but it only shows one item.
My HTML code :

```
<select v-model="selectedBrand" 
        id="cboBrand"
        name="cboBrand">
    <option v-for="b in brandList" :value="b.Id">
       {{ b.Name }}
    </option>
 </select>
```

My javascript code:

```
mounted : function() {  
var vm = this;
M.AutoInit();
axios.get('MyUrl')
.then( function(response) {
 var data = response.data
 if (data.Status == 'OK') {
    vm.brandList = data.Data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(vm.brandList));
    var cbo = document.getElementById("cboBrand");
    console.log(cbo);
    M.FormSelect.init(cbo);
  } else {
    M.toast({html: data.Message});
 }
})
.catch(function (error) {
  M.toast({html: error});
});
```

The data object is :

```
{ 
"message": "", 
"currentAction": "", 
"selectedBrand": 1,
 "brandList": [ 
    { "Id": 1, "Name": "SportsBetting" }, 
    { "Id": 2, "Name": "BetsOnLine" } 
], 
"selectedAction": 1, 
"actionList": [], 
"selectedField": 1, 
"fieldList": [], 
"selectedType": 1, 
"typeList": [], 
"validationRows": [] 
}
```

I am positive there is data in brandList, but in the select is only shown the first item of the array...

TIA,
Yamil

Comment: coud you show your data object ? `data(){return ...}`

Comment: { "message": "", "currentAction": "", "selectedBrand": 1, "brandList": [ { "Id": 1, "Name": "SportsBetting" }, { "Id": 2, "Name": "BetsOnLine" } ], "selectedAction": 1, "actionList": [], "selectedField": 1, "fieldList": [], "selectedType": 1, "typeList": [], "validationRows": [] }

Comment: please update your question with that data to be more clear to read